# How to scrape the name of the img source and data when a span is involved Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have created a code that scrapes the table from a website but for some reason it scrapes only some of the information. when i use .String it prints none for two of the other data needed. when i remove the .string it pints the li class and the data i need aswell as span. it also prints out the image source but i just need the name of the image and the fixture.

my code is;

```
import urllib2

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.livefootballontv.com/').read())

for row in soup('div', {'id': 'tv-guide'})[0]('ul'):
    tds = row('li')
    #ths = row('th')
    print tds[0].string, tds[1], tds[2].string, tds[3].string, '/n'
```

this prints out;

Saturday 08 February 2014 Central Coast Mariners vs Melbourne VictoryHyundai A League  06:30am None /n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use .text on the span one and for the other i used .img['alt'] this worked fine